# How to Remove a folder by condition during Uninstall process?

Tags: inno-setup

I have two products, so I created two installers, lets say **Showcase** and **Interior**. My products used one Common third party application, So I supply this each installer.

If I want to install Showcase product, during installation, it will check whether Interior product installed or not. If Interior product doesn't install, then Third party files will be installed in a Common folder.

***Showcase*** will install like this:

```
          {pf}\Company_Name\
                     ----->Common
                             --->Third party player
                     ----->Showcase
                             --->Showcase product related files
```

Now I want to install **Interior**, like **Showcase** installation, it will checks **Showcase** was installed or not. Present **Showcase** already installed. So it will  installs only Interior things and doesn't install Third party files.

Now the file structure like following:

```
         {pf}\Company_Name
                     ----->Common
                             --->Third party player
                     ----->Showcase
                             --->Showcase product related files
                     ----->Interior
                             --->Interior product related files
```

Now my Question is,

When I uninstall **Showcase** product, it'll also remove the Common folder. So Interior product will not run. So I want to tell Uninstaller, don't uninstall Common folder by condition. How to do this?

Please help..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

1) What is **{app}** folder for your installation(s)? *{pf}\Company_Name* or directly *Showcase* and *Interior* folders?

2) The uninstaller usually delete all files in {app} folder which were copied during installation. That means: if someone creates new file in {app} folder (let say some config file) the uninstaller does not delete it.
As {app} folder is deleted only if empty (by default) uninstaller keep it (appropriate message is shown).

3) What flags do you use for installing the files? You can use **uninsneveruninstall** flag on *Common* files so uninstaller will never delete them and you can delete them in [Code]. (You need to detect somehow whether they are not used by other software).

There is no exact solution at this moment (more information needed) but the last chance is copy all files manually (e.g. extract them to Temp and copy in [Code]) so you have full control over them.

Comment: Thanks @Slappy for your information. 


I found solution from [http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=100789&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#100789].  It's work like i want.

Now i'll explain what you pointed out....
1)Installation structure for Showcase product:

    {app} ---> {pf}\Company_name\Showcase

  As well as For Interior product:

    {app}--->{pf}\Company_name\Interior

2)Yes , default uninstaller delete all files except newly created one

3)As you said that, We can also use "uninsneveruninstall" for Shared folder. But it must delete by code.

So finally "sharedfile" is solution